# Помогите плиз. Как объеденить 2 объекта массива в один, используя PHP?

Tags: php, json

У меня есть проблема. У меня есть два объекта, которые записаны в разные переменные. Для того, чтобы объединить, я делаю так:

```
$result = array_replace_recursive($json1, $json2);
file_put_contents('js/allProducts.json',json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Потом я записываю этот объект в JSON-файл. Но у меня один из массивов почему-то обрезается. Мне нужно, чтобы эти два объеденились в один объект, а не объект в котором эти два объекта. Я думаю, вы поняли, что я имел ввиду. Жду помощи!)

```
первый
[{
"Id": "010",
"Title": "Милый дом 100мл",
"Price": "210",
"ImgSrc": "standart_candle.jpg",
"Description_1": "бергамот, чистый хлопок",
"Description_2": "пион, лаванда, морские ноты, петигрен",
"Description_3": "мускус, сандаловое дерево",
"Count": "40"
}]
второй
[{
"Id": "110",
"Title": "Candle box набор 100мл",
"Price": "320",
"Description_1": "Коробочка, для создания аромасвечи своими руками.",
"Description_2": "Создайте свечу самостоятельно, чтобы ещё больше наслаждаться моментом зажжения.",
"ImgSrc": "new_category.jpg",
"Count": "20"
}]
```

А мне нужно чтобы было так:

```
[{
"Id": "010",
"Title": "Милый дом 100мл",
"Price": "210",
"ImgSrc": "standart_candle.jpg",
"Description_1": "бергамот, чистый хлопок",
"Description_2": "пион, лаванда, морские ноты, петигрен",
"Description_3": "мускус, сандаловое дерево",
"Count": "40"
},
{
"Id": "110",
"Title": "Candle box набор 100мл",
"Price": "320",
"Description_1": "Коробочка, для создания аромасвечи своими руками.",
"Description_2": "Создайте свечу самостоятельно, чтобы ещё больше наслаждаться моментом зажжения.",
"ImgSrc": "new_category.jpg",
"Count": "20"
}]
```

Comment: чтобы мы поняли, что вы имеете в виду, напишите что из себя представляют ваши объекты, и что вы от них хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: я изменил вопрос

Comment: Берешь и добавляешь все свои данные из БД в один массив сразу. `$data = []; while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){ $data[] = $row1;} while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){ $data[] = $row2;}`.

Comment: array_merge просто и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то чем этот вариант плох? Наверное вы его пробовали...

```
$obj_merged = (object) [$json1, $json2];
```

Но мне кажется красивее было бы:

```
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge_recursive((array) $json1, (array) $json2);
```

Хотя он выдаёт не то что вы просите, но выглядит оно логичнее, чем объект список объектов...

```
/* 
object(stdClass)#3 (8) {
  ["Id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "010"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "110"
  }
  ["Title"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "Милый дом 100мл"
    [1]=>
    string(29) "Candle box набор 100мл"
  }...

*/
```